# Blank lines in doxygen \code section

Tags: doxygen

I have a \code section in a *.dox-file:

```
\code{*.cpp}
    foo

    bar
\endcode
```

but Doxygen 1.8.8 removes all blank lines and the tabs in the *.html output. There is no INPUT_FILTER. What else can cause this behavior?

Comment: I've not been able to reproduce the described behavior with doxygen 1.8.8 nor with 1.8.9. for the given example (anyway the * should be removed). Can you give a more complete example (i.e. changes in the default Doxyfile and a, small full source code file.

Comment: Thank you, finally it works: I have shell scripts that copy the html-output to the web server. These scripts replaced the doxygen.css by an old modified version.

Comment: I hope you are aware of the option HTML_EXTRA_STYLESHEET in the Doxyfile.

Comment: @Geom, please post this as an answer to your question and mark it as accepted.

Comment: @Nick: I just wanted to do that but Stackoverflow behaves strange. When I'm logged in, there is no box to write an answer (Firefox, Linux). When I do not log in the box appears and I can write the answer but to submit it I must log in - and then the answer disappears. When I tried again it said something like "suspicious action"